# Opening "Kataster/DKM - Grundstücke" files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, xml, parcel, austria

[This website](https://gis.stmk.gv.at/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page) seems to provide cadastre data for [Styria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styria) (a state in Austria). Writing `kataster` in the search (`Suche`) field gives:

[image]

If I click on the third result, i.e. "Kataster/DKM - Grundstücke", I see:

[image]

If I then click on <kbd>View XML</kbd>, I get to [this page](https://gis.stmk.gv.at/geoportal/rest/document?id=%7B08553BFD-168D-47E8-8753-69FF19F85DAE%7D), which is not a WMS server, and the type of XML files I can read with QGIS are pointing to WMS servers. The <kbd>details</kbd> section lead to [this page](https://gis.stmk.gv.at/geoportal/catalog/search/resource/details.page?uuid=%7B08553BFD-168D-47E8-8753-69FF19F85DAE%7D), which states:

> "Security Restriction:    unlimited"

which suggests that I should be able to read in these files, and I am doing something wrong.

How can I read Styrian Cadastre data in QGIS?

Comment: For Germany there exists a converter provided by Claas Leiner which extracts a .shp-file and an excel-list from downloaded cadastral xml-data. Maybe there's something similar for Austria.

Comment: Does it say anywhere that the data itself (and not only metadata) can be downloaded? This does not seem clear to me. Otherwise, I would directly contact the agency to ask how to access the data, if they are freely distributes as OGD over the web or if you have to order them.

Comment: The XML (metadata), says the data is restricted `<gmd:resourceConstraints>
<gmd:MD_SecurityConstraints>
<gmd:classification>
<gmd:MD_ClassificationCode codeList="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ClassificationCode" codeListValue="restricted">restricted</gmd:MD_ClassificationCode>
</gmd:classification>
<gmd:userNote>
<gco:CharacterString>unclassified</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:userNote>
</gmd:MD_SecurityConstraints>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the site you linked only provides metadata, not the data itself. To access the Open Government Data of Steiermark, go to this site: https://data.steiermark.at/.

There, access the `Datenkatalog` and choose the dataset you're interested in. There, you will get a link to the actual data, see this example:

[image]